Which pseudo R-squared value is best for GLS models?
I need help understanding some stats. I am a beginner.
I applied GLS models (with Spatial Correlation Structures, e.g., CorExp). For my GLS models, I calculated pseudo R-squared values using the nagelkerke function in R. This function generates three types of pseudo R-squared values: 1. McFadden, 2. Cox and Snell (ML), 3. Nagelkerke (Cragg and Uhler).
Each of these values differs significantly in my results. I don't know which is the most appropriate to use in the specific context of a GLS model (and which one I should report in my results).
Thank you for reading,
L.

Do the different pseudo R**2 give you different ordering of the model goodness on hold out data? Or is it "different numbers but same ordering" (which would be fine...)

Welcome to Cross Validated! $1)$ What do you want to learn from your pseudo $R^2$ value? $//$ $2)$ What is done in the work you cite?
